# Trigger click when clicking on parent

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce product gallery that has 4 square thumbnails each containing images with widely diverging dimensions. The images cannot be either wider or taller than it's square container like this example thumbnail:

[image: Thumbnail example]

- Gray outline: container
- Green: padding
- Blue: image

Right now you have to click the image instead of its square container to show the related slide. This causes a lot of frustration when you have images about the width of a pencil. I already added the maximum amount of padding to increase the clickable area before shrinking the images too much and there are no `<a>` tags I can manipulate. It's just the image.

```
<ol class="flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
        <img>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I had the idea of triggering the click on the `<img>` by adding a .click() function to the parent li but this gives me a "Maximum call stack size exceeded." error.

```
jQuery(document).click(function() {
    ...

    // Simulate click on img
    jQuery(".flex-control-thumbs li").find("img").trigger("click");
});
```

Is there any way to "extend" the clickable area to the entire thumbnail instead of just the image or maybe simulate a click on the image by clicking on the container using jQuery?

EDITED after fix:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".flex-control-thumbs li", function() {
    ...

    // simulate click
    event.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).find("img:not(.flex-active)").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Why not attach the listener to the ol rather than the entire document?

Comment: @scrappedcola Honestly I'm not sure... I've been fighting with this slider for a while no (for multiple reasons) but this seemed to do what I wanted at the time.

Comment: The entire document is overkill, as the lovely error is reminding you. Take a few minutes to relax and let go the frustration. Then try out Bhushan's answer. Worst case is that you would need to wrap the image in another element that you can set display:block on and then set an explicit width.

Comment: And adding event.stopPropagation on the image would be your friend in this case to prevent another click overload

Comment: @scrappedcola You guys are amazing it's working now. event.stopPopagation did indeed fix the error, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: you can add click listener on li elements and when you click on images it will traverse to parent li

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".flex-control-thumbs li", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Got it, but shouldn't I add something to trigger the same event as clicking the image?

Comment: if you have handled parent click event then child click even handler not required unless you want to do some different operation

Comment: Thanks @Bhushan it's working now this really helped :-)

Comment: @Marrrc, Happy to help you. You can accept this answer if you find it helpful